# How to have a Viewgroup containing multiple ImageButton in android?

Tags: android, view, custom-component, viewgroup, clicklistener

While creating a custom Viewgroup,is it possible to have multiple Imagebutton within it?
is it possible to place Image buttons in our own position.

If all these are possible,how to call the click listener which extending this viewgroup?

My ViewGroup have to look like this image
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup{

    public CustomViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        //addImageView();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        //addImageView();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, 
                defStyle);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        //addImageView();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("onLayout");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        drawBackground(canvas);
        addImageView();
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Bitmap background =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.shape_quarter_circle);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0,0, null);
    }
    private void addImageView()
    {
        ImageView imageOne = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageOne.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_icon));
        //imageOne.setWillNotDraw(false);
        addView(imageOne);
        requestLayout();

    }
```

I am trying to draw a background and place some ImageView on the top of the background.
In this code Background image is getting displayed correctly. but i could not see the ImageView drawn upon it.
Am i going in the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the things you said are possible.

you just use

```
yourViewGroup.setOnClickListener()
```

for your view group click listener.

Comment: i have extended myclass with viewgroup. but i am not able to place any imageView on that. where and how should i add the imageView?

Comment: Yashwanth Kumar, but this will create only clickListener for my entire ViewGroup but not for individual images right?

Comment: you should look at one of the android source codes of ViewGroup and see how children are added to it, you do the same to your custom viewGroup and set the onClickListeners for the child ,while you add them to the parent which is ViewGroup.